# Running Android Studio 2.3.3, I am told Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'. > java.lang.IllegalStateException: aidl is missing

Tags: android

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdVqx.png

Running Android Studio 2.3.3, if I attempt to run a program, I am told my aidl is missing. I have read through the other questions, but I am only seeing posts from 2015.  I attempt to follow the instructions and downgrade my "Compile Sdk Version" and then downgrade my "Build Tools Version." However, I am not given any other compile sdk version options other than 7.1.1 Nougat. Build tools versions only offers me 25.0.3 or 26.0.1 .  The error code is below. I am new to this, I know a bit of Java and just wanted to explore a bit. But I've search for an hour and a half how to solve this. Maybe I am just dumb. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Post your build.gradle..

Comment: Your SDK & build tool version should be the same

Comment: give the solution bro

Answer (score 0):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.tarun.myapplication"
    minSdkVersion 20
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner 
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: thanks both  Vishal Vaishnav &  Rajesh Murugan.  this my  build.gradle code